# Android Kotlin 'Cannot infer type parameter T'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I just converted from java to kotlin and faced some issues from
`viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)`
Any idea for this?

> Cannot infer type parameter T in fun <T : ViewDataBinding!> inflate(p0: LayoutInflater, p1: Int, p2: ViewGroup?, p3: Boolean): T!
> None of the following substitutions
> (LayoutInflater,Int,ViewGroup?,Boolean)
> (LayoutInflater,Int,ViewGroup?,Boolean)
> can be applied to
> (LayoutInflater,Int,ViewGroup?,Boolean)

```html
abstract class BaseFragment<T : ViewDataBinding?, V : BaseViewModel<*>?> : Fragment() {
    var baseActivity: BaseActivity<*, *>? = null
    private var rootView: View? = null
    var viewDataBinding: T? = null
    private var VM: V? = null

    /**
     * Override for set binding variable
     *
     * @return variable id
     */
    abstract val bindingVariable: Int

    /**
     * @return layout resource id
     */
    @get:LayoutRes
    abstract val layoutId: Int

    /**
     * Override for set view model
     *
     * @return view model instance
     */
    abstract val viewModel: V

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is BaseActivity<*, *>) {
            baseActivity = context
            context.onFragmentAttached()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        VM = viewModel
        setHasOptionsMenu(false)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)
        rootView = viewDataBinding?.root
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        baseActivity = null
        super.onDetach()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewDataBinding?.setVariable(bindingVariable, VM)
        viewDataBinding?.executePendingBindings()
    }

    interface Callback {
        fun onFragmentAttached()
        fun onFragmentDetached(tag: String?)
    }
}
```

```html
abstract class BaseViewModel<N>(val dataManager: DataManager, val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider) : ViewModel() {
    private var mNavigator: WeakReference<N>? = null
    private var mCompositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable?
    override fun onCleared() {
        mCompositeDisposable!!.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }

    fun setNavigator(navigator: N) {
        mNavigator = WeakReference(navigator)
    }

    val navigator: N?
        get() = mNavigator!!.get()

    var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable?
        get() {
            if (mCompositeDisposable == null || mCompositeDisposable!!.isDisposed) {
                mCompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
            }
            return mCompositeDisposable
        }
        set(compositeDisposable) {
            mCompositeDisposable = compositeDisposable
        }

    init {
        mCompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataBindingUtil.inflate()` knows nothing about your `T`. My guess is that you will need to do a manual cast to `T`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's a good guess. `Type inference` means ability to automatically deduce, the type of an expression at compile time. Compiler cannot do this, so you need to help it

Comment: @CommonsWare Resolve this. 
Just change `BaseFragment<T : ViewDataBinding?, V : BaseViewModel<*>?>` ViewDataBinding to NotNullable